# Как заменить 2 и более пробела между двумя фрагментами текста на 1?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня в файле между фрагментами `div class="name"` и `finish</div>` есть двойные и более пробелы перемешанные с текстом, я попытался очистить этим регулярным выражением(через ctrl+h)

```
(?<=div class="name)  +(?=finish</div>)
на
(?<=div class="name) (?=finish</div>)
```

Но не получилось, так как сохранив целосность текста между этими двумя фрагментами заменить все двойные и более пробелы на 1?

Что бы из этого

```
My   text is        There
```

Стало это

```
My text is There
```

Comment: `"My   text is        There".replace(/ +/g,' ')` (комментарии съедают лишние пробелы, добавьте по вашему вкусу)

Comment: проблема в том что нужно именно между 2 фрагментами на каждой строке(на одной строке несколько дивов в которых не нужно убирать пробелы и один где нужно)

Comment: я бы просто заменил  `два пробела+` на `один пробел`(regex), но нужно конкретно из фрагментов удалить =(

Comment: Что такое фрагмент?

Comment: Часть текста, в моем случае есть куча различных div'ов c разными класами и на каждой строке есть `<div class="name">` в конце которого всегда finish<div>

Comment: (?<=div class="name).+?(?=finish</div>) выделяет весь текст между двумя фрагментами текста, а мне надо что бы выделялись только пробелы(два и более) и заменялись на 1 пробел

Answer (score 0):

Написал код на python, заменяющий табы, пробелы и все новые линии на 1 пробел

То что мне надо, оставлю его здесь:

```
import re
with open(file, 'r') as f, open(file_fixed, 'a') as x:
    main_file = f.readlines()
    for line in main_file:
        extracted = re.search(r"(?<=div class="name").*?(?=finish</div>)", line)
        if extracted:
            data = extracted.group(0)
            change = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', data).strip()
            changed = re.sub(r'  +', ' ', change).strip()
            x.write(line.replace(data, changed))
        else:
            x.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

У строки есть метод `split`, который без параметров разбивает строку по пробельным символам (несколько пробелов считаются как один разделитель). Нужно просто строку разбить, потом собрать обратно, сделав разделителем один пробел:

```
text = 'My   text is        There'
result = ' '.join(text.split())
print(result)  # My text is There
```